Inaccurate FT Sensor Values in Gazebo Classic 11 (22.04 ROS2 Humble)
ROS2 Humble | Gazebo Classic 11 | Ubuntu 22.04
The project that I am working on in ROS2 still uses Gazebo Classic, having not yet migrated over to Ignition. The force/torque sensors I've put into the URDF for Gazebo successfully publish data, but the data is very inaccurate, with static values dependent on spawning height above the ground before settling.
I've made the modifications listed in this reference page (https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-FT-sensor) to get data from the sensor is being published. Without these minor syntax changes, nothing is published, but the data is successfully published over the specified topic post-changes.
To test behavior in isolation, I made the simple test URDF below:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="test_gazebo">

  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.014" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.014" iyz="0" izz="0.014"/>
    </inertial>
      <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="distal_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.014" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.014" iyz="0" izz="0.014"/>
    </inertial>
      <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 1.1"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 1.1"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="jt" type="continuous">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="distal_link"/>
    <axis xyz= "0 0 1"/>
  </joint>    

<!-- Force-torque plugin at steering joint-->
    <gazebo reference="jt">
      <provideFeedback>true</provideFeedback>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="ft_sensor_jt" filename="libgazebo_ros_ft_sensor.so">
        <!-- <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
        <topicName>/ft_sensors/limb_${limb_number}</topicName>
        <jointName>jt</jointName> -->
        <ros>
          <namespace>ft_sensors</namespace>
          <remapping>wrench:=/jt</remapping>
        </ros>
        <joint_name>jt</joint_name>
        <body_name>base_link</body_name>
        <frame_name>distal_link</frame_name>
        <update_rate>50.0</update_rate>
        <gaussian_noise>0.001</gaussian_noise>
      </plugin>
    </gazebo>
</robot>

... and spawned it with a launch file in the default Gazebo world. Given the mass of 1kg on the top joint, I'd expect to be seeing about -9.8 N in the z-direction of the ft sensor; instead, it's about -8, with an additional -7 N in the x-direction. The specific values end up being dependent on what height the robot is spawned at; if spawned inside the ground, for instance, it pops up to ground level as expected but then can give very low magnitudes on the order of 2-4 N in the z-direction.
This same configuration got me much more accurate results in ROS1 and Ubuntu 20.04; as far as I can tell, it seems to only be an issue on ROS2.
Has anyone gotten accurate readings from the FT sensors in Gazebo 11 in ROS2?
I want to avoid having to redo the entire simulation architecture for this part of the project in moving over to Ignition.

0
Can you try to read the sensor from the gz topic to see if it returns the same values? Can you report the exact Gazebo version used for the ROS 1 and ROS 2 experiments, and the ROS 1 URDF?
